# Limit the space between of the child items when using using display flex space between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div (100% width) with 3 buttons in it. I need to keep them with a little margin one to another.

I used bootstrap and this is what I get when I used display flex and space-between option.

[image]

The code;

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-element {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
}

.child-element .selected {
    background: #FFED00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="child-element" data-option="1"><span style="color:#000">First</span></button>
    <button class="child-element" data-option="2"><span style="color:#000">Second</span></button>
    <button class="child-element" data-option="3"><span style="color:#000">Third</span></button>
</div>
```

This is how I want to see them;

[image]

What are the changes I need to do here? Also, I think using margin-left,right is not a good option. But correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove `justify-content: space-between` and add some gap such as `gap: 8px`:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    align-items: center;
    
    /* add gap */
    gap: 8px;
}

.child-element {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
}

.child-element .selected {
    background: #FFED00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="child-element" data-option="1"><span style="color:#000">First</span></button>
    <button class="child-element" data-option="2"><span style="color:#000">Second</span></button>
    <button class="child-element" data-option="3"><span style="color:#000">Third</span></button>
</div>
```